# Perl: Sub's arguments explain

Tags: perl

In Perl, all sub's argument is writing to the `@_` array, like this:

```
call_any_sub($a,$b,$c);
sub call_any_sub {
  my $s_a = shift;
  my $s_b = shift;
  my $s_c = shift;
}
```

But if I want to pass the array as an argument to sub, I should use:

```
call_any_sub(@data_array);
sub call_any_sub {
  my @data = @_;
}
```

Instead of similar:

```
call_any_sub(@data_array);
sub call_any_sub {
  my @data = shift;
}
```

So, why does @data_array replace the array of arguments and not written in it (as expected)?

Comment: I understand that, but why `@data_array` replaces `@_` instead written in it, like `@_[0]=>@data_array; @_[1]=>$other_var` ?

Comment: @Arkham.vm It doesn't. The array is flattened and its elements passed to your subroutine and inserted into `@_`.

Comment: @TLP, in fact it is the same replacement, with the loss of a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand what [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) does.

The `shift`/`unshift` pair of commands are parallel to the `pop`/`push` pair of commands. All of these commands operate on *arrays*. By default, `shift` (and only `shift`) assumes the `@_` array when called in a subroutine and `@ARGV` when called in the main program. This means the following two statements are identical in a subroutine:

```
my $foo = shift @_;  # Explicit Argument
my $foo = shift      # Implicit Argument
```

Perl's parameter passing is an *interesting concept* because it doesn't really do named parameter passing like almost all other programs. Instead, everything is passed as one long list of scalars. This makes it hard when you aren't passing in a scalar.

It works okay if I am only passing in a single hash or array:

```
munge_hash ( %foo );

sub munge_hash {
    my %hash = @_;
    ...

}
```

And, you have to be careful if you're passing in multiple arguments and an array. In this case, the array must be the last in your list of arguments:

```
my $foo = "floop";
my $bar = "bloop";

my @array = qw(loop coop soop);

munge_this ( $foo, $bar, @array );

sub munge_this {
   say join ":", @_;  # Prints "floop:bloop:loop:coop:soop"
   my $var1 = shift   # floop
   my $var2 = shift   # bloop
   my @arry = @_      # The rest is the array passed.
```

However, things really fall apart if you're passing in multiple arrays or hashes. All of the elements get merged into a single list of scalars represented by `@_`.

```
munge_two_arrays ( @foo, @bar );

sub munge_two_arrays {
    # Problem! Elements of both arrays are in @_.
    # How do I separate them out?
}
```

Thus, it is common not to pass in a whole array, but an *array reference*:

```
munge_two_arrays( \@foo, \@bar ); # These are array references

sub munge_two_arrays {
    my $array1_ref = shift;
    my $array2_ref = shift;

    my @array1 = @{ $array1_ref } # Dereference array references to make arrays
    my @array2 = @{ $array2_ref } # Dereference array references to make arrays
}
```

This keeps the values of the two arrays from getting merged into a single `@_`.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about passing multiple arrays, now i get it.

Answer (score 6):

One can only pass a list of scalars to a subroutine (and that's all they can return). After all, the arguments are presented to the sub as an array (`@_`), and arrays can only contains scalars.

You can either (inefficiently) recreate the array in the sub

```
 sub foo {
    my @bars = @_;
    say for @bars;
 }

 foo(@bars);
```

or you can pass a reference to the array

```
 sub foo {
    my ($bars) = @_;
    say for @$bars;
 }

 foo(\@bars);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second example use `foo(\@bars);` or `foo([@bars]);`?

Comment: Oops, meant to. Fixed. (`foo([@bars])` would have the same inefficiency as the first snippet.)